# Firefox : Add Default Preset String to Web Searches

Tags: firefox

I've looked a lot on this matter for the past hour and there doesn't seem to be any thread directly or indirectly covering my issue, so I thought about asking you. Please forgive me if the answer was already available somewhere else.

**So what I want is to be able to input a preset string that would add up by default to any query I make using the address bar or the search bar of Firefox Browser.**

I've looked deeply into the preferences and there's no way I found to make this happen.
I haven't found any appropriate plugin either.

However I strongly believe it would be rather easy to do such a thing for someone who is just a bit familiar with this, and I can't imagine to be the first person who'd like to do this.

So do any of you know of any convenient way ? or I should get started making my own firefox plug-in ? In that case, can somebody guide me a bit on how I would do it ?

Thanks a lot for your answers :)

PS : My goal is mainly to block some websites in results so for example adding the string "-site:websiteidontlike.com" to all my searches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get any answer here, so I wanted to make an update for people who would arrive here in the future looking for an answer, to tell you I found some solutions in here :
https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/acuj8a/firefox_add_default_preset_string_to_web_searches/

1) You can add a bookmark to your search engine with the wanted added string on it :

- Right click in the search box of the site you want to use for your search
- Click "Add a keyword for this search"
- After you added a keyword go to this new bookmark and change its properties
- You should see a url with "%s" somewhere in there
- After "%s" which is your search term just add "+-site: websiteidontlike.com"
- Now you can use this search with the keyword in your url bar

2) A script provided by jscher2000 (with Tampermonkey) which permits to block search results for websites you don't like which was my objective : 
https://openuserjs.org/scripts/jscher2000/Google_Hit_Hider_by_Domain_%28Search_Filter_Block_Sites%29

Hope this will be of use to some people :).